# PrintScreen and then paste on Email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to take a PrintScreen from the sheet and then paste it on a new e-mail.

I want it in the body not as an attachment. I have no idea how to paste the image to the body.

```vb
Sub SetRecipients()
    Dim aOutlook As Object
    Dim aEmail As Object
    Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents

    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A13")
    For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
        strRecipients = "email.test@gmail.com" 'strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
    Next
    aEmail.Subject = "Indicator activity warning ( TestMailSend )"
    aEmail.Body = ********* DONT KNOW *******
    aEmail.To = strRecipients
    aEmail.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I detest `Sendkeys` but this works...

```
Sub SetRecipients()
    Dim aOutlook As Object, aEmail As Object
    Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents

    Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A13")

    For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
        strRecipients = "email.test@gmail.com" 'strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
    Next

    aEmail.Subject = "Indicator activity warning ( TestMailSend )"
    aEmail.To = strRecipients
    aEmail.display '<~~ This is required so we can send keys to it

    Wait 2 '<~~ wait for 2 seconds for email to get displayed

    SendKeys "^({v})", True '<~~ Paste

    DoEvents '<~~ Waiting for paste to happen

    '~~> Finally send
    aEmail.send

    Set aOutlook = Nothing
    Set aEmail = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: There might be a better way using SendMessage API, Lemme check and get back to you.

Comment: Ohhhhh!! Nice work using the .display thing to show and then paste! I'd never though of that!
Thank you sir! It's working perfectly!

Comment: Kool :) If I manage to come up with the Sendmessage code then I will update the above post. BTW whic outlook version are you using?

Comment: Hmm i'll have to run this macro in 2 different pcs. One with 2007 and the other one with 2010